# How to print list as int in OCaml?

Tags: list, int, ocaml

Say I have any list, for example

```
let lista = [1;2;3;4;5;6]
```

How do I write this as

```
int = 123456
```

so that i can later pass it to a function?

I tried

```
  let rec print lista =
  match lista with
  []->()
  |a::lista ->print_int a; print lista;;
```

but i dont get expected result, only

```
 - : unit = ()
```

I know about int_of_string, so whether my function returns string or int doesnt really matter.

Comment: What have you tried? How would you do it with pen & paper?

Comment: I edited my post to show what i tried

Comment: Do you want to iterate through the list of integers, create a string from it and then pass that the function?
Or do you want to create a new integer from the list of ints?

Comment: Pass int to another function, but since `int_of_string` exists it doesnt matter

Comment: Your function doesn’t return anything because it’s just printing values. You seem like you want to convert each element to a string and concat until there’s no more elements in the list, then convert that string to an int then return. Try that instead of printing

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution :

```
lista 
|> List.fold_left (fun a x -> a * 10 + x) 0;;
```

the accumulator is multiplied by 10 and we add the current element of the list

the second parameter for initializing the accumulator to 0.

List.fold_left is very useful for processing a list.

If you need to print the result modify the code adding the line to print directly the result :

```
lista 
|> List.fold_left (fun a x -> a * 10 + x) 0
|> print_int;;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're quite close to a solution: instead of `print`ing the solution to the standard output, you should produce a string for each number and append them together. Here are functions you will need:

[`val string_of_int : int -> string`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALstring_of_int)

and

[val (^) : string -> string -> string](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VAL(%5E))

Alternatively, you could bypass `int_of_string` and implement a direct solution by noticing that:

```
to_int [a; b; ...; c; d] = ab...cd
                         = d + 10 * (c + 10 * (... + 10 * (b + 10 * c)))
```

i.e. that this has a neat recursive structure.

Comment: But my function wont return anything, only  `- : unit = ()`

Comment: If you `print` stuff, yes. But if you build a `string`, it'll have type `[int] -> string`.

Comment: So how to do it? Im out of ideas

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @gallais easy to chain a series of transformations to achieve this: `let list_to_int lst = lst |> List.map string_of_int |> String.concat "" |> int_of_string`